# Simulate time running faster with Protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, typescript, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Ive been running protractor to automate my tests recently and I was wondering if there were a way to simulate a faster run time so that I dont have to sit through the browser.sleep() times Ive added. I need to use sleeps and waits because of hardcoded/necessary timers that need to be run. 
In other words, I'd like the timers and browser.sleep() to run faster than their usual time. I don't want to be waiting for 30 minutes for the test to run. I do not want to decrease the actual number I input into the browser.sleep() function. Any direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I need to use sleeps and waits because of hardcoded/necessary timers that need to be run" - What do you mean? Do you have an example?

Comment: create a variable for the values in `browser.sleep()` and then change that variable only when you're running tests

Comment: @GG. I am testing a round robin tournament that has wait times to allow for users to check-into the game. Also there are 15 minute delays between rounds. I cannot change these times as they are a core of the functionality. What I would like is to decrease the actual time I have to wait. So for example. I would like my browser to act as if every millisecond is a second. Therefore it would go through everything quicker.

Comment: No, that's not possible from the browser... If the browser can control the speed of the timers on your app then you have serious security issues.  If you can't change the timer on the application, the only way Protractor is going to run faster is if you remove those `browser.sleep()`'s and replace them with implicit waits (as you should).